# How to create a confirm alert box?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a button. When I click on the button, the alert box should be visible.
The alert box will have two buttons, Yes and Cancel
If I click on Cancel button, the alert box should be closed.
When I click on Yes button, It will take me to another php page. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad (and unclear). It would be beneficial for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: Do little search first, and show your code and error if any.

Answer (score 0):

Wait I understood. Here are two examples for you I'm explaining.

```
<button onClick="delete()"> goTo </button>
    <script> 
             function goTo ()
             {
                  var x = confirm('Are you ready to go this site');
                  if( x === true )
                  {
                        open('https://www.fiverr.com/dev_sal');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      document.write('sorry, to hear it!');
                   }
              }
   </script>
```

if you don't need else condition So, put off. merely use if condition.

Cheer you Be happy if made some mistake to tell me, please?